# How does Linux recognize a file as a certain file type, and how to programmatically change it?

Tags: java, linux, byte, file-type

I am crating a program in java that reads an Input Stream of a file, encrypts it by changing around the numbers of the bytes based on what the password is, and creates a new encrypted file.

**For example:**
I created a test file that contained the words:
`This is a test to see if the encrypter project works.`
When I read the bytes in java, I get:
`[84, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 97, 32, 116, 101, 115, 116, 32, 116, 111, 32, 115, 101, 101, 32, 105, 102, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 101, 110, 99, 114, 121, 112, 116, 101, 114, 32, 112, 114, 111, 106, 101, 99, 116, 32, 119, 111, 114, 107, 115, 46, 10]`
So then I take the value of each byte, and subtract the unicode value of the passwords, and get the absolute value of that. Then I write that to a file.

I was playing around with different algorithms to encrypt it, and started testing it out on a test text file. I am using Linux, so so there are no file extensions (eg. .txt, .pdf, etc...) I noticed after a few times of encrypting it, that the computer no longer recognized it as a text file, but instead, as an image file! (meaning when you click on it, by default, it tries to open the file in an image editor)

So here are my questions:

#### 1. What causes the computer to recognize a file as a certain file type?

- I am guessing that it has something to do with certain bytes that it looks at somewhere in the file, but beyond that, I'm lost.

#### 2. Where in the file is this information stored?

- I was hoping to be able to keep the file as the same file-type even after encryption, so I was thinking, that if, for example, the file-type information was in the first 10 bytes, I would encrypt everything after that, but leave those first 10 bytes alone for example.

#### 3. Is file-type information standard?

- Do these bytes have a meaning that is standard across all platforms (ie. a pdf file is a pdf file no mater what computer you use it on. Is that because of the `.pdf` extension, or is it because of the bytes that are somewhere in the file.)

#### 4. Assuming the file-type is recognized because of bytes in the file, how can I change the file-type?

- Where can I find a listing of what bytes mean what in a file?

Comment: I think it is HEADER mime-type?

Comment: What will `man file` do? I am not trying to do anything in the linux command line, I am trying to physically write bytes to a file using java to change the file type.

Comment: It will answer your question.

Comment: I tried it, it opened the file. I'm not interested of the contents of the file, but the byte numbers. The actual file says `This is a test to see if the encrypter project works.`, but the byte numbers are `[84, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 97, 32, 116, 101, 115, 116, 32, 116, 111, 32, 115, 101, 101, 32, 105, 102, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 101, 110, 99, 114, 121, 112, 116, 101, 114, 32, 112, 114, 111, 106, 101, 99, 116, 32, 119, 111, 114, 107, 115, 46, 10]`

Comment: "I am not trying to do anything in the linux command line" --- you should! Open the terminal and start learning. `man file` is as good a command is any. It will not harm you or your computer. Or try typing `man file` in a Google search, it might land you on the right page.

Comment: "I tried it, it opened the file." --- you must be doing something wrong. Type `man file` verbatim, do not substitute your file name anywhere.

Comment: @n.m. that isn't what I meant. I am familiar with the linux command line, I just meant that in this case, I was trying instead to figure out how to allow my java program to change / keep the same the file-type of a given file. Btw, you were right, I thought you meant man [filename] instead of man file.

Answer (score 4):

On traditional UNIX systems, files are identified solely by looking for particular patterns of bytes appearing in the file.

The `file` command uses a  `magic` configuration file (often `/etc/magic`, or `/usr/share/file/magic`) which contains the rules defining those byte patterns.

That's it - there's no special extra meta-data - it's all done by analysis of the content.

Comment: @UmNyobe true, as it derives from [Magic Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Comment: how does it analyze them (what does it look for, in say, a text file)

Comment: @Ephraim see `man file` and `man magic` - all the info is there.  A text file is kinda what you have left over if none of the binary formats were recognised and all that's left is 7-bit ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it will be within the first few bytes of the file.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Internal_metadata):

> **Internal Metadata**
>   A second way to identify a file format is to store information regarding the format inside the file itself. Usually, such information is written in one (or more) binary string(s), tagged or raw texts placed in fixed, specific locations within the file. Since the easiest place to locate them is at the beginning of it, such area is usually called a file header when it is greater than a few bytes, or a magic number if it is just a few bytes long.

Although the file-type is not necessarily going to be stored in the first few bytes, it can be stored [elsewhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#File_header)

> The metadata contained in a file header are not necessarily stored only at the beginning but might be present in other areas too, often including the end of the file; it depends on the file format or the type of data it contains. Character-based (text) files have character-based human-readable headers, whereas binary formats usually feature binary headers, although that is not a rule: a human-readable file header may require more bytes, but is easily discernible with simple text or hexadecimal editors. File headers may not only contain the information required by algorithms to identify the file format alone, but also real metadata about the file and its contents. For example most image file formats store information about image size, resolution, color space/format and optionally other authoring information like who, when and where it was made, what camera model and shooting parameters was it taken with (if any, cfr. Exif), and so on. Such metadata may be used by a program reading or interpreting the file both during the loading process and after that, but can also be used by the operating system to quickly capture information about the file itself without loading it all into memory.

Another method of storing the file-type inside the file is using [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number)

> One way to incorporate such metadata, often associated with Unix and its derivatives, is just to store a "magic number" inside the file itself. Originally, this term was used for a specific set of 2-byte identifiers at the beginning of a file, but since any undecoded binary sequence can be regarded as a number, any feature of a file format which uniquely distinguishes it can be used for identification. GIF images, for instance, always begin with the ASCII representation of either GIF87a or GIF89a, depending upon the standard to which they adhere. Many file types, most especially plain-text files, are harder to spot by this method. HTML files, for example, might begin with the string  (which is not case sensitive), or an appropriate document type definition that starts with

The file-type doesn't even have to be stored inside the file. Other methods include [filename-extentions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension) or even [External Metadata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#External_metadata)

> A final way of storing the format of a file is to explicitly store information about the format in the file system, rather than within the file itself.
>   This approach keeps the metadata separate from both the main data and the name, but is also less portable than either file extensions or "magic numbers", since the format has to be converted from filesystem to filesystem. While this is also true to an extent with filename extensions — for instance, for compatibility with MS-DOS's three character limit — most forms of storage have a roughly equivalent definition of a file's data and name, but may have varying or no representation of further metadata.

There are many other ways too, but these tend to be the most common.