# how to intentionally corrupt a file in java

Tags: java, file, document, corruption, corrupt

***Note:*** Please do not judge this question. To those who think that I am doing this to "cheat"; you are mistaken, as I am no longer in school anyway. In addition, if I was, myself actually trying to cheat, I would simply use services that have already been created for this, instead of recreating the program. I took on this project because I thought it might be fun, nothing else. Before you down-vote, please **[consider the value of the question it's self](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote)**, and not the speculative uses of it, as the purpose of SO is not to judge, but simply give the public information.

---

I am developing a program in java that is supposed intentionally corrupt a file (specifically a .doc, txt, or pdf, but others would be good as well)

I initially tried this:

```
public void corruptFile (String pathInName, String pathOutName) {
    curroptMethod method  = new curroptMethod();
    ArrayList<Integer> corruptHash = corrupt(getBytes(pathInName));
    writeBytes(corruptHash, pathOutName);
    new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(new File(pathInName));
    //  "/home/ephraim/Desktop/testfile"
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getBytes(String filePath) {
    ArrayList<Integer> fileBytes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    try {
        FileInputStream myInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
        do {
            int currentByte = myInputStream.read();
            if(currentByte == -1) {
                System.out.println("broke loop");
                break;
            }
            fileBytes.add(currentByte);
        } while (true);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(fileBytes);
    return fileBytes;
}

public void writeBytes(ArrayList<Integer> hash, String pathName) {
    try {
        OutputStream myOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(pathName));
        for (int currentHash : hash) {
            myOutputStream.write(currentHash);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //System.out.println(hash);
}

public ArrayList<Integer> corrupt(ArrayList<Integer> hash) {
    ArrayList<Integer> corruptHash = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> keywordCodeArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Integer keywordIndex = 0;
            String keyword = "corruptthisfile";

    for (int i = 0; i < keyword.length(); i++) {
        keywordCodeArray.add(keyword.codePointAt(i));
    }

    for (Integer currentByte : hash) {


        //Integer currentByteProduct = (keywordCodeArray.get(keywordIndex) + currentByte) / 2;
        Integer currentByteProduct =  currentByte - keywordCodeArray.get(keywordIndex);
        if (currentByteProduct < 0) currentByteProduct += 255;
        corruptHash.add(currentByteProduct);

        if (keywordIndex == (keyword.length() - 1)) {
            keywordIndex = 0;
        } else keywordIndex++;
    }

    //System.out.println(corruptHash);
    return corruptHash;
}
```

but the problem is that the file is still openable. When you open the file, all of the words are changed (and they may not make any sense, and they may not even be letters, but it can still be opened)

so here is my actual question:

**Is there a way to make a file so corrupt that the computer doesn't know how to open it at all (ie. when you open it, the computer will say something along the lines of "this file is not recognized, and cannot be opened")?**

Comment: Any file, even a corrupt one, can be opened in notepad. It will just look like garbage.

Comment: Replace the entire file contents with the word `Corrupted!`

Comment: Make it an .exe file, with the following source code: `void main() { MessageBox("this file is not recognized, and cannot be opened"); }`

Comment: Just finish your homework on time.

Comment: Honestly? I know how, but i don't want to help, because it looks like you try to use this program to cheat. Sorry. Learn to stay focused on something this will help you more. I know this doesn't solve your problem, and some might not like this, but i think this has to be said.

Comment: @Adi I am not using this program to cheat, as I am no longer in school anyway. I took on this project because I thought it might be fun. If you can answer this question, please do so, as the purpose of SO is not to judge, but simply give the public information.

Comment: LOL. Your teachers must by really lenient. If my professor even lost my file, he would blame me!

Comment: "Don't judge me just because I'm being dishonest."

Comment: @TonyEnnis please do not turn this post into an argument. Simply because this program has the potential to allow people to cheat, does not mean that it shouldn't be created. I am not asking anyone not to judge me, as it is impossible to tell people to control their opinions. I am simply asking people not to allow their personal opinions get in the way of the true purpose of SO. (Btw, there is nothing illegal about this at all, even if one were to use it. And there are already other services that can do this, so if I wanted to cheat, I wouldn't bother re-creating the program.)

Comment: My prof always made homework (paper submission) due midnight Friday.  We were supposed to slip it under her office door before then.  Of course realistically, as long as you slipped it under her office door before Monday morning, she would accept it as on time.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to look into the [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). Also, it is almost always the case that a program recognizes its file by its very start. So open the file and scramble the first 5 bytes.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question and being non-judgmental. Btw, you have also answered another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131631/what-causes-the-computer-to-recognize-a-file-as-a-certain-file-type-and-how-can) I had. You may want to write an answer on that one too, as it was pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: The existing answer there is already quite good, if maybe too general. The beginning of a file is usually called 'magic'. The guy there says that the 'magic' file on a UNIX defines rules for byte patterns, which is more general than if it defined just the literal bytes occurring at the beginning of a file. I always thought it did just that and wasn't as general as the poster there says, but I'm not positive.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to fully corrupt an arbitrary file is to replace *all* of its contents with random garbage. Even then, there is an infinitely small probability that the random garbage will actually be something meaningful.

Depending on the file type, it may be possible to recover from limited - or even from not so limited - corruption. E.g.:

- Streaming media codecs are designed with network packet loss take into account. Limited corruption may show up as picture artifacts, or even as a few lost frames, but the content is usually still viewable.
- Block-based compression algorithms, such as `bzip2`, allow undamaged blocks to be recovered.
- File-based compression systems such as `rar` and `zip` may be able to recover those files whose compressed data has not been damaged, regardless of damage to the rest of the archive.
- Human-readable text, such as text files and source code files, is still viewable in a text editor, even if parts of it are corrupt - not to mention its size that does not change. Unless you corrupted the whole thing, any casual reader would be able to tell whether an assignment was done and whether the retransmitted file was the same as the one that got corrupted.

Apart from the ethical issue, have you considered that this would be a one-time thing only? Data corruption does happen, but it's not that frequent and it's *never* that convenient...

If you are *that* desperate for more time, you would be better off breaking your leg and getting yourself admitted to a hospital.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways:

1. Your professor accepts Word documents.  Infect it with a macro virus before sending.
2. "Forget" to attach the file to the email.
3. Forge the send date on your email.  If your prof is the kind that accepts Word docs, this may work.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Like I said, I am not looking for how to cheat, I am only looking for how to write a program to corrupt the file.