# How does the Linux command `file` recognize the encoding of my files?

Tags: linux

How does the Linux command `file` recognize the encoding of my files?

```
zell@ubuntu:~$ file examples.desktop 
examples.desktop: UTF-8 Unicode text

zell@ubuntu:~$ file /etc/services 
/etc/services: ASCII text
```

Comment: Do ```man file``` in the terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Linux recognize a file as a certain file type, and how can I change it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131631/what-causes-the-computer-to-recognize-a-file-as-a-certain-file-type-and-how-can), [How to find encoding of a file via script on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/805418/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) is pretty clear

> The filesystem tests are based on examining the return from a stat(2)
>   system call...
>
> The magic tests are used to check for files with data in particular
>   fixed formats. The canonical example of this is a binary executable
>   (compiled program) a.out file, whose format is defined in #include
>    and possibly #include  in the standard include
>   directory. These files have a 'magic number' stored in a particular
>   place near the beginning of the file that tells the UNIX operating
>   system that the file is a binary executable, and which of several
>   types thereof. The concept of a 'magic' has been applied by extension
>   to data files. Any file with some invariant identifier at a small
>   fixed offset into the file can usually be described in this way. The
>   information identifying these files is read from the compiled magic
>   file /usr/share/misc/magic.mgc, or the files in the directory
>   /usr/share/misc/magic if the compiled file does not exist. In
>   addition, if $HOME/.magic.mgc or $HOME/.magic exists, it will be used
>   in preference to the system magic files. If /etc/magic exists, it will
>   be used together with other magic files.
>
> If a file does not match any of the entries in the magic file, it is
>   examined to see if it seems to be a text file. ASCII, ISO-8859-x,
>   non-ISO 8-bit extended-ASCII character sets (such as those used on
>   Macintosh and IBM PC systems), UTF-8-encoded Unicode, UTF-16-encoded
>   Unicode, and EBCDIC character sets can be distinguished by the
>   different ranges and sequences of bytes that constitute printable text
>   in each set. If a file passes any of these tests, its character set is
>   reported.

In short, for regular files, their [magic values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) are tested. If there's no match, then `file` checks whether it's a text file, making an educated guess about the specific encoding by looking at the actual values of bytes in the file.

Oh, and you can also [download the source code](ftp://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/lfs/lfs-packages/9.0/file-5.37.tar.gz) and look at the implementation for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR: Magic File Doesn't Support UTF-8 BOM Markers

(and that's the main charset you need to care about)

The source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/lindenb/magic) so anyone can search it.  After doing a quick search, things like `BOM`, `ef bb bf`, and `feff` *do not appear at all.*  That means [UTF-8, Byte-Order-Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) reading is not supported.  Files made in other applications that use *or* preserve the BOM marker will all be returned as "charset=unknown" when using `file`.

In addition, none of the config files mentioned in the [Magic File manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) are a part of magic file v. 4.17.  In fact, `/etc/magicfile/` doesn't exist at all, so I don't see any way in which I can configure it.

If you're stuck trying to get the ACTUAL charset encoding and magic file is all you have, you can determine if you have a UTF-8 file at the Linux CLI with:

```
hexdump -n 3 -C $path_to_filename
```

If the above returns the following sequence, `ef bb bf`, then you are 99% likely in possession of a BOM-marked UTF-8 file.  [This is not a 100% certainty,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2223882/2430549) but it is far more useful than `magic file`, where it has no handling whatsoever for Byte Order Marks.